How to make one of two parameters mandatory, so that at least one of the two is always present?
mandatory would make both parameters required. I just need to make sure either path or fileList is always present.
I have been making do with the following but its not ideal:
function foo{
    Param(
    [string[]]$path
    [string[]]$fileList
    )
    if (($null -eq $path) -and ($fileList -eq "")){Write-Error -Message "Paths or FilieList must be used" -ErrorAction Stop}
}

win11/pwsh 7.4

Are you looking to have only one of them be available too or both params can be used together ?

@SantiagoSquarzon both are intended to be used at the same time, at the very least one of them.


Try the following:
function foo {
  [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'PathAndFileList')]
  Param(

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='PathOnly', Mandatory)]
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='PathAndFileList', Mandatory)]
    [string[]]$Path,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='FileListOnly', Mandatory)]
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='PathAndFileList', Mandatory)]
    [string[]]$FileList

  )
  # Diagnostic output: Show which parameters were bound.
  $PSBoundParameters
}

The key is to use parameter sets:

One parameter-specific set each, for when only only one of the two parameters is bound on invocation (PathOnly, FileListOnly).

A shared one (PathAndFileList) for when both parameters are bound.

By marking both parameters as Mandatory in all parameter sets they belong to, argument-less invocations trigger an interactive prompt for providing value(s) to the mandatory parameter(s), or - in CLI sessions launched via the -NonInteractive parameter - trigger an error.

Via the DefaultParameterSetName property in the [CmdletBinding()] attribute you get to choose the
default parameter set, which in interactive execution, in turn determines which parameter(s) are prompted for in argument-less invocations (or, generally speaking, in invocations where not all mandatory parameters in the target parameter set are bound).

Caveat: If you choose PathAndFileList as the default parameter set, both -Path and -FileList are prompted for in argument-less interactive calls, and must not be empty (by default, array-typed parameters do not accept an empty array), i.e. you must provide at least one value for both in order for the call to be made.
While there is a [AllowEmptyCollection()] attribute, the problem is that if you add it to both parameters, you again enable an effectively argument-less invocation, if you enter nothing for / pass @() to both parameters.

That said, the UX of the interactive prompts is generally poor and limited with respect to what parameter types it supports.

See GitHub issue #4068 for a discussion, including a proposal to always throw an error in the absence of a mandatory parameter value (as with -NonInteractive), which would make this problem moot.






It works surprisingly well, just as I needed it to. I am gonna learn about this parameter set stuff. Thank you.

Glad to hear it helped, @Ralf_Reddings. I've added an explanation and documentation link to the answer. Note the discussion of the problematic aspects of interactive prompting for missing mandatory parameter values.

Is there anything related to parameter sets on the PowerShell roadmap? Where can I find a PowerShell roadmap? I looked in PowerShell/PowerShell-RFC, but did not find anything. Where should I be looking?

@lit, I'm not aware of an official roadmap that is maintained on an ongoing basis, which a quick web search seems to indicate as well.
